# VS 2015(Community) Designer crashes with FileNotFoundException

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, uwp

I just installed visual studio 2015 community edition in a windows 10 HP pc (updating from windows 8.1) the problem is that the designer doesn't load.

This is the error I am getting

```
An Unhandled Exception has occurred

Stack trace

System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)

   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)

   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)

   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)

   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ObjectFactory.CreateInstance(CatalogEntry entry)

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.RemoteObjectFactory.IsolationContextObjectFactory.CreateInstance(CatalogEntry entry)

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.RemoteObjectFactory.Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.IRemoteObjectFactory.CreateMarshaledInstance(String interfaceTypeName)

   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)

   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 

   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)

   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.IRemoteObjectFactory.CreateMarshaledInstance(String interfaceTypeName)

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.CreateInstance[T]()

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry, IServiceProvider serviceOverrides)

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<StartTask>b__0()

   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()

   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

I have searched online with no luck. I haven't seen anyone having this exception.
I have seen some people with NullReferenceExceptions and their solutions. But no one with FileNotFound

**EDIT: Reinstalling solved the issue**

Comment: I would try repairing visual studio 2015 to see if it installs the missing file.

Comment: @KenTucker Thanks for the comment. I tried repairing it and it didn't work. I'll try reinstalling all together